# Range of even numbers using recursion c

Tags: c, recursion, stack

I know that there are a lot of questions and answers about recursion here, but hear me out. In my program, I'm trying to get a range of only even numbers. The user enters two numbers between -5000 and 5000; if the numbers are out of order (that is, greater number is entered first) the numbers are swapped into order; and in the recursion function, a simple function return 0 or 1 determining if the current value is even or odd using `n%2`. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to actually work with recursion.

```
int recursive_function(int first_number, int second_number)
{

printf("\n    Entering sum function for range %d to %d",
                                                        first_number, second_number);

if(first_number > second_number)
    return 1;

else
{
    if(is_even(first_number) == 0)
    {
        printf("\n        Adding: %d", first_number);
        return (first_number += recursive_function(first_number + 1, second_number));
        printf("\nThis equals added");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n        Skipping: %d", first_number);
        return (first_number += recursive_function(first_number + 1, second_number));
        printf("\nThis equals skipped");
    }
}

}
```

The program works, in terms of the recursion terminating, I just do not understand how I am supposed to pop the rest of the stack. Here is a representation of what is supposed to be the output. (Assuming the values are 10 and 20)

```
Processing the range 10 to %20:
Entering the sum function for range 10 to 20
    Adding: 10
Entering the sum function for range 11 to 20
    Skipping: 11
Entering the sum function for range 12 to 20
    Adding: 12
Entering the sum function for range 13 to 20
    Skipping: 13
Entering the sum function for range 14 to 20
    Adding: 14
Entering the sum function for range 15 to 20
    Skipping: 15
Entering the sum function for range 16 to 20
    Adding: 16
Entering the sum function for range 17 to 20
    Skipping: 17

...

Entering the sum function for range 20 to 20
    Adding: 20
Entering the sum function for range 21 to 20   (recursion stops here)
(This next part is where I don't know how this happens)
Exiting sum function for range 21 to 20 with result: 0
Exiting sum function for range 20 to 20 with result: 20
Exiting sum function for range 19 to 20 with result: 20
Exiting sum function for range 18 to 20 with result: 38
Exiting sum function for range 17 to 20 with result: 38
Exiting sum function for range 16 to 20 with result: 54

....

Exiting sum function for range 11 to 20 with result: 80
Exiting sum function for range 10 to 20 with result: 90
The sum of all even numbers in the range 10 to 20 is: 90
```

I know this has to do with popping all these statements "off the stack". The problem is all the research I have done gives me explanations with the assumption that one truly understands recursion whereas I am an amateur. Could any one help and explain in English?

Comment: How goes life after passing Dr. H's class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what is happening write down a sequence of calls on a piece of paper. Use a smaller range, say 18 to 20.

Here is an example. I omitted most of the function body leaving lines with recursive calls.

```
recursive_function(18, 20):                        <<< initial call, depth 0
  printf("\n    Entering
  ...
  printf("\n        Skipping: %d", 18);            <<< Execution goes to this
  return (18 += recursive_function(19, 20)):       <<< recurses, depth 1
    printf("\n    Entering
    ...
    printf("\n        Adding: %d", 19);
    return (19 += recursive_function(20, 20)):     <<< depth 2
        printf("\n    Entering
        ...
        printf("\n        Skipping: %d", 20);
        return (20 += recursive_function(21, 20)): <<< depth 3
            printf("\n    Entering
            ...
            if(21 > 20)
               return 1;                           <<< end of recursion
        printf("\nThis equals skipped");           <<< left over at depth 2
    printf("\nThis equals added");                 <<< left over at depth 1

  printf("\nThis equals skipped");                 <<< left over at depth 0
```

Now you can collect all printf statements sequentially and have a resulting output. Note that in your code you skipped "Exiting..." part, while the output has it.

**Popping off the stack**. Popping off the stack is done for you by the compiler. It happens when function returns. You should worry about returning at a proper moment, not about how to pop off the stack.